# Where I should include reset css to avoid problems with my existing css?

Tags: css, sass, css-reset

Hello

I had this problem:
[image]
and to solve it I included reset.css form here - > http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css

Now my site look worse, because some margins are 0, and it look like this:

[image]
please. look at the footer - can't change margin and padding, because of reset.css.

I tried to include reset.css first, but it didn't help.

Question is -  how I can solve this ?

Comment: You seem to have a misconception of the concept of a "css reset." With the reset, you are "resetting" the *browser's* default CSS. (Every browser applies some basic styling to various elements.) You are *not* resetting *your* CSS. So you apply the CSS reset first to clear the browser defaults, and then apply your own on top. This way you'll know it looks the same in every browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just find out the specific problem and solve it manually, instead of including all that code for one fix.

To me it looks like your ul has a margin on it, do "navClass" { margin: 0; } and see if that fixes it

But, for future reference, CSS resets should ALWAYS be before your css, or else it will overwrite what you have created

Edit: realised you have fixed your nav, but want to fix the footer. Just add a margin/padding to it, you was relying on the default, which you have set to 0 so you need to manually add it back in.

Comment: Tried to use it only for ul, li, ol and didn't help. It could be caused by Bootstrap or not ?

Comment: I just can't get - margins are in my footer, but I'm overriding it with reset.css yes ? In my footer.css.scss nothing changed and nothing changing, when I try to. Where I should change it ?

Comment: I can't tell you that without seeing your code/style sheets. Can you link me to the webpage we are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You should include the reset.css **first**. And then overwrite those values with what you need.

So in your instance, you have been relying on some default values when making your css. reset.css alters those values, and your page breaks. So now you should set those values manually.
For instance, you will need to add margin and padding to your footer.

Comment: I don't want to do it for ALL my divs. So I try to find appropriate code for my proble(dropkick) and use it, yes ?